# How can a laravel project work without routes and controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I imported bagisto (an eCommerce laravel project ) from GitHub. i configured it on localhost and it works mostly. I wanna make changes in this project to make my own website . When i look at the source code, i realized the routes and controller files were literally empty. Im wondering, how can a laravel project work without having routes or controllers. There is definitely something i am missing.
I'd share the web.php file or controllers but they are empty, If you require to look at any other file, please let me know, ill add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to go to the packages folder to see the details predefined routes, controllers, view files.

Take a look.

[bagisto/packages/Webkul/Admin/src/Http/routes.php](https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto/blob/master/packages/Webkul/Admin/src/Http/routes.php)

[bagisto/packages/Webkul/Admin/src/Http/Controllers/DashboardController.phpe](https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto/blob/master/packages/Webkul/Admin/src/Http/Controllers/DashboardController.php)

[bagisto/packages/Webkul/Admin/src/Resources/views/account/edit.blade.php](https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto/blob/master/packages/Webkul/Admin/src/Resources/views/account/edit.blade.php)

Comment: thank you soo much!!